# exception maximum file size asp:fileupload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a form where a user can submit a file through asp:fileupload, but want to display a specific error message if the user uploads a file exceeding 10MB. However, when I put a try catch statement, my error message does not get displayed, only the default one. How do I make sure it gets displayed?

```
Try
            If fuAttach.HasFile Then
                Dim filename As String = fuAttach.FileName
                fuAttach.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename)
                Dim reqContext As SoapContext = SDWS.RequestSoapContext
                Dim dimeAttach As New DimeAttachment("image/gif", TypeFormat.MediaType, HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/" & fuAttach.FileName))
                reqContext.Attachments.Add(dimeAttach)
                SDWS.createAttachment(SID, "doc_rep:400842", objectHandle, "description", fuAttach.FileName)
                File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename)
                lblThankyou.Text = "<p style = ""font-size: small"">Thank you, your request has been submitted!</br></font></br></br>You will receive an email in several minutes from autonotify@arlingtonva.us confirming that a ticket has been entered into our system.</p>"
            Else
                lblThankyou.Text = "<p style = ""font-size: small"">Thank you, your request has been submitted!</br></font></br></br>You will receive an email in several minutes from autonotify@arlingtonva.us confirming that a ticket has been entered into our system.</p>"
            End If
        Catch
            lblThankyou.Text = "<p style = ""font-size: small"">Your file upload may not exceed 10MB</br></font></br></br></p>"
        End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find some answers here:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+max+file+upload+size&submit=search

**UPDATE**

Setting it for files up to 15MB:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="15360" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I've already set the maximum length. The thing I'm asking about is how exception handling for when the user exceeds that length.

Comment: What error message are you getting? (comment out the try catch and see...)

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: Maximum request length exceeded.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.

Comment: I'm wondering exactly where I would need to put the try/catch statement.

Comment: It looks okay to me where you have it; caveat, I'm not a VB guy. I'm more inclined to focus on where you have set the max file size - is it set in the root Web.Config file in your project? For testing, just omit the try catch and let the system report the error... I am updating my answer.

Comment: You're presuming in your code that it is a file size error - presume nothing. From the catch block, try sending an email to yourself with the Exception details.

Comment: <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
        
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">

        </compilation>. I'm pretty sure it's a file size error, because I tested with files below 10MB where I don't get an error and files above 10MB where I do get an error as displayed in my above comment without the try/catch. Adding the try/catch to the btnSubmit_Click makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to check the file size prior to uploading, because the server has yet to receive the whole file.
And There's no native API for File System access in browsers. I found some people done this with javascript in IE [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12415/Testing-file-size-before-uploading-it), using ActiveX file system object but it won't work on other browsers.

There are better solutions to handling large file uploads in ASP.NET. A custom HttpHandler can provide a better user experience by displaying upload progress and allowing you to handle a file size problem in a more controlled fashion. If you interest, there was a long list of Forum Post [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/55127.aspx).

You can also consider for third party controls such as [NeatUpload](http://neatupload.codeplex.com/) which is free.